# Choosing MongoDB collections structure for similar data structures

Tags: mongodb

What is the better way to store similar structures in MongoDB? Choose one collections for all or one for each structure? Any benefits of having one/few?

For example, I have to store some logs, for further analytics. There is a common part for each structure and some data specific for some stat type, like:

```
{ 
  timestamp: ...,
  client: { ... },
  type: 'stats_for_item1',
  data: { 
     id: ObjectId('xxx'),
     field1: 1,
     field2: 2 
  } 
},
{ 
  timestamp: ...,
  client: { ... },
  type: 'stats_for_item2',
  data: { 
     id: ObjectId('zzz'),
     field3: 3,
     field4: {
        field5: [5, 1]
     }
  } 
}
```

As you see we have common part, and `data` field, with few different fields for `item1` and `item2`.

Seems that only `timestamp` and `type` fields will be indexed (and _id of course). And there is limited number of such items, say 3 item types in total. There will be a lot of writes, and small amount of reads

So, my question, how to organize such structures? Use one big collection `stats` and store everything there? ot create few collections `stats_item1`, `stats_item2` and `stats_item3`. What is optimal? Any benefits? From mongo perspective, for sharding/indexing/querying/locking/etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably keep one collection. In the case you do get another stat-type later, you don't have to re-architect your code around the new collection that you then have to be adding.  You can search specifically on items where you have a specific type by creating an index on "type", but you can also search through *all* items because you have them all in a collection with an index on "timestamp". (Please note that MongoDB also adds an _id field to every document, and to that one it will add an index too).

For sharding, you will need to pick a key per collection. I don't know what your write/read ratios are and how you intent to read data, but I suspect you're doing some sort of logging with some analysis later. In that case, perhaps a shard key on "client" makes most sense. timestamp is probably going to be a poor choice as it'd force all writes unto one shard.

The difference between one or three collections for locking doesn't make a lot of difference, as right now mongoDB doesn't do locking per collection (just per server instance with lock yielding in 2.0, and per-DB with lock yielding in the upcoming 2.2).

cheers,

Derick